# How to fix broken speaker connection terminal

Tags: amplifiers, speakers

Amp model: Roland JC-77

- How to fix broken speaker connection terminal?

OR

- Where to buy a replacement part?

See picture below

[image]

Comment: Closing as this doesn't fit our site scope.

Comment: You are so right Doktor Mayhem! It should have gone to the electronics stackexchange indeed. I am glad some people had the chance to help before you closed the question though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the sort of thing you can normally buy, because it comes riveted to the speaker.

Avoid pulling on it.  The speaker wire is fragile.

Does the speaker still work?  If so, I would attempt to glue it back on with something nice and strong, such as two-part epoxy (Araldite) and something to act as a splint across the break.

Comment: yes speaker works! will try to glue with 2 part epoxy!

Comment: Just be sure, when the job's permanent, not to let the two connections touch each other - amps don't like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of broken speakers around - pop to a music shop repair section. Should get one for free! But only if you're handy with a soldering iron, and gentle handling wires.

Otherwise, two part epoxy will do - make certain the two wires/connections can't short against each other or the metal of the speaker frame.

Comment: The OP already has a broken speaker, how does getting another one for free help?

Comment: @ojs - aw, come on! Most speakers have broken cones or coils. In 60 yrs, I've only ever had the same broken bit like OP's once, and have thrown away many, many speakers with the bit OP needs intact.